# Which event of cefsharp browser will be called when a js function is called?

Tags: javascript, cefsharp

I am using cefsharp embedded browser (latest version-79) in my Winform application?
First, I use cefsharp browser to load a web page, all relevant js files are loaded.
Then, I want to get the url or name of a js file every time a function in the js file is called when users interact with the web page. 
So that I need to know which event of the browser occurs when a js function is invoked?
Please help me.

Comment: There is no such event. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Actually I am trying to edit the content of the loaded js file. Because there are some bugs in the js file that prevent the html content from displaying correctly.

Comment: You can write some javascript to override those methods and replace them with your own. There are a few ways to solve this, that's the easiest.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will follow the article https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#response-filtering to inject js code into the loaded content.

Comment: You can load your own version of the js files which its probably similar. See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#request-interception

Comment: You help me a lot. Finally, I can load my our js file to replace the loaded version by overriding the function GetResourceHandler of ResourceRequestHandler class and Return ResourceHandler.FromFilePath(jsFilePath). Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CefSharp does not currently have such an event.